# How do I know if sessions are successfully being managed by redis?

Tags: php, session, redis, phpredis

I've set my values in my `PHP.ini` as shown below. Redis works and the sessions work. 
Now what I really wonder is How do I know that sessions are being handles & stored at Redis?
I've searched everywhere and I cant find how would I validate that is working with Redis.

I need to be able to check somehow that the sessions are stored there.

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://host1:6379"
extension=redis.so
```

my PHP info  shows

```
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your sessions were being successfully managed by redis, you would see new keys being added to redis when a session is created.

You can ask redis to list its keys on the command line:

```
$ redis-cli keys "*"
1) "some-redis-session-keys"
2) "should-be-in-this-list"
```